# Gradle ivy.xml dependencies not added

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, ivy

I am running into an issue when publishing artifacts to using the 'ivy-publish' plugin.   There are multiple modules where I publish a custom jar or a couple custom jars and the ivy.xml file does not add the project dependencies. Would this be because they are custom jars or something else?

Here is a sample of how I am publishing.

```
publishing{
    publications{
        client(IvyPublication){
            organisation "${group}"
            module "${module_name}"
            revision "${version}"

            artifact (file("${buildDir}/dist/${module_context}.jar")){
                name "${module_name}"
                extension 'jar'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are the dependencies that are being used by the project.

```
dependencies{
    compile (group:"com.xxxxxxx", name:"xxxx-svcs-common", version:"${xxxx_svcs_common_service_version}", transitive:false)
    compile (group:"com.xxxxxxx.cache", name:"xxxx-cache", version:"${xxxx_svcs_common_svcs_cache_version}", transitive:false)
    compile (group:"com.sun.jersey", name:"jersey", version:"1.8", transitive:false)
    compile (group:"com.oracle", name:"coherence", version:"3.7.1", transitive:false)
    compile (group:"com.xxxxxxx.cache", name:"xxxx-cache", version:"${xxxx_entsvcs_common_svcs_cache_version}", transitive:false)
}
```

And this is the ivy.xml that is generated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0">
  <info organisation="xxx.xxxxxxx" module="xxxx-service-name" revision="xxx2014_jun-201406051004" status="integration" publication="20140605100413"/>
  <configurations/>
  <publications>
    <artifact name="xxxx-service-name" type="jar" ext="jar"/>
  </publications>
  <dependencies/>
</ivy-module>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
        artifact (file("${buildDir}/dist/${module_context}.jar")){
            name "${module_name}"
            extension 'jar'
        }
```

use

```
        from components.java
```

The first simply publishes the specified file. The second will publish the jar generated by the `jar` task of the java plugin and generate dependency meta data from the `runtime` configuration.

Comment: So @Perrynfowler, it has to be created using the Jar task? It can't be created using ant.jar?

Comment: Yes `components.java` takes the output from the jar task. If you want to use ant.jar you will need to set up the dependencies in the ivy meta data yourself using the methods on IvyPublication. I'm unsure why you would want to use ant.jar though?

Comment: Well before I knew about the dependencies, ant.jar was much easier to use because I was creating the jars in a loop. I have since re-factored and everything seems to be looking much more like an actual Gradle build.

Comment: Do you know how to add the dependencies from a custom Jar task? Not the task added by the Java plugin.  I am creating multiple jars using the Jar task but none of the runtime dependencies are being added. Do I have to add them to the components.java somehow or do something ?

Comment: I think you would have to use `descriptor.withXml()` however the situation sounds a bit strange to me. If you have several jars with *different* dependencies then they probably belong in different publications. If they all have the same dependencies then you can just use the `jar` task for one of them and `components.java`

Comment: Completely forgot that was possible. Thanks, that worked perfectly.